# ANN symbolic parameters

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

My input parameters for the neural network contain symbolic data. I do not understand whether it is possible to submit data in this form or needed to normalize.
Is it not true? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Neural networks are not symbolic networks. They work only on the numeric data. If by "symbolic" you mean categorical (like "cat", "dog") then typical approach is to use one hot encoding. However, if by symbolic you mean actual symbolic (like "a+b-2^c", "a*b") then there is no specific way to go, and it is a problem-specific question, impossible to answer without exact specification of data and lots of research.